# CakePHP. Do not works "on => create"

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I set up rule 'isUnique' and set 'create' value for 'on' option.

Complete code:

```
'username' => array(
     'notempty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notempty'),
        'message' => 'Empty field',
        'required' => true,
     ),              
     'between' => array(
        'rule' => array('between',3,25),
        'message' => 'Too long value'
     ),
     'unique' => array(
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        'on' => 'create',
        'message' => 'Already taken',
        'required' => true,
     )
  )
```

But when I'm trying to log in, I get the error message. Why?

CakePHP 2.2.1

Comment: Are you getting the error without 'on'?

Comment: Edit your question and put more code in it. Put AppController, UsersController (or where your login and registration is), model and view. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have `'required' => true` set, which requires the key to be present when validating. This conflicts with the `'on'` key, as explained here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#one-rule-per-field

Instead, make it required only when creating.

```
'unique' => array(
    'rule' => 'isUnique',
    'on' => 'create',
    'message' => 'Такой никнейм уже занят',
    'required' => 'create', // change this to 'create'
 )
```

Comment: the 'required' key makes the FIELD required and the 'on' key makes the RULE being applied. so they are two different things!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that when you are trying to log in, CakePHP thinks that you are creating a new record (CakePHP identifies it as new record because you don't provide ID of the item like you do when you are editing some item).

The solution could be to create a custom validation function which would check for unique username all the time except when logging in.

Comment: yeah, now I'm actually using custom functions to check this kind of fields

Comment: I have just faced similar problem and haven't been able to find a good solution so after some research I posted mine here